# Busca dinâmica em tempo real

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, web-service

Na empresa que trabalho vamos implementar um sistemas no qual o Back-end será PHP e o banco de dados será CACHE (Intersystem).

A base de dados fica em um servidor diferente de onde será implementado o sistema em PHP, acontece que toda a comunicação entre eles será via Webservice para muitas consultas e registros ele funciona bem, porém será implementado um sistema de busca

A busca terá que ser dinâmica pois enquanto o usuário digita algo o sistema vai sugerindo resultados que coincidam com o que está sendo digitado, como nas imagens que estou pondo em este *post*.

Para ter esse tipo de resultado em tempo real precisarei usar o AJAX ou jQuery certo?

Dá para usar o PHP + Webservice + AJAX ou jQuery para dar respostam em tempo real enquanto o usuário digita algo?

[image: Exemplo 1]

[image: Exemplo 2]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A resposta é SIM... dá para obter resposta em tempo real quando um utilizador digita algo, no entanto alguns são os pontos a ter em consideração.

No caso da utilização do JQUERY e PHP como solicitado, requisição por AJAX é o caminho a tomar.

Numa análise **simplista** irá precisar de "ouvir" eventos de teclas no INPUT.
exemplo com **keypress** mas existe o **keyup** ou o **keydown** (coloco o enter, para outras teclas ver documentação):

```
$( "#target" ).keypress(function( event ) {   
    if ( event.which == 13 ) {
        alert('enter pressionado');  
    }
});
```

Como resultado a cada tecla pressionada poderás obter o conteúdo do INPUT:

```
var content = $( "#target" ).val();
```

Entregar `content` ao `asynchronous HTTP (Ajax) request` e assim que é retornado pelo `webservice` o resultado da pesquisa atualize o `html`.

**Como disse esta é uma forma simplista e porquê?**

Porque a velocidade de entrega do resultado da pesquisa nunca irá ser a mesma e porque quem digitar rápido... imagine os `requests` sucessivos. Bom na verdade com a implementação de uma QUEUE de requests pode ultrapassar esse problema, mas mais uma vez não seria nada prático neste caso particular.

Não é boa prática realizar `AJAX requests` à velocidade que se introduz o texto. E se o webservice estiver bem preparado irá concerteza bloquear a um determinado ponto ou negar-se a responder. Não se esqueça que um webservice é um serviço exposto, logo acedido por muitos. Imagine todos a teclar ao mesmo tempo. :)

Se o `webservice` for "seu" então **você determinará** as regras, no entanto, desgraçado do servidor que responder por um serviço exposto desta forma.

Existem algumas técnicas a implementar mas deixo uma simples que terá resultados imediatos, ou seja a utilização de um timer... exemplo: setTimeout. imagine algo do género:

```
$.fn.input_search = function () {
    var timer = 0;
    var input = $(this);
    input.keyup(function (e) {
        var code = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
        if (code > 45 || code === 32 || code === 8 || code === 13) {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            timer = setTimeout(function () {
                alert('neste momento coloca a chamada AJAX '.input.val())
            }, 200);
        }
    });
};
```

Criei este plugin, não o testei mas a lógica não será certamente muito diferente. Cada tecla pressionada será validada quando a mesma for "largada" e o timer é reiniciado.

Por simplicidade o caracter terá de ser maior que 45 (consulte a tabela). Quando parar de teclar então o timer irá aguardar o tempo estipulado. No exemplo é de 200 milisegundos e executa o código dentro do `setTimeout()`.

Realize testes e ajuste o valor do timer. Aumente o seu valor, no entanto, quanto maior, mais tempo demora a pesquisa a iniciar.

Coloquei validações que me lembrei em que o timer deve de ser reiniciado ao teclar, como tecla de espaço (32), backspace (8) e o enter (13)... veja outras hipóteses pois trata-se de um exemplo.

Answer (score 1):

Você deverá fazer algo do tipo toda vez que o usuário digita algo realiza a busca, como [nesse exemplo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vEWXrg) pegando em *real time* o que é digitado

Feito isso você deverá do lado do servidor trazer resultados, na volta deverá ter um *autocomplete*, pode ser com jQuery ui mesmo.

Answer (score 0):

Sim, é só você colocar a URL do WebService no lugar onde ficaria o caminho do arquivo.

Exemplo em Ajax do Jquery:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://ws.exemplo.com/'
});
```

Espero ter ajudado!

Lembrando que o WebService tem de estar preparado para receber as informações!